# InvalidOperation when Get Items from Sqlite and Remove Duplicate items

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to get items from the sqlite database (There are about 6,000 items in the database)
Some items are duplicates Therefore, I want to remove this duplicate information when I get items

I used the following code

```
public async static Task<List<myModel>> GetAllItems()
        {
            using var db = new dbContext();
            var query =
                from item in db.myTable.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First())
                select new myModel
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Name = item.Name,
                    ...
                };
            return await query.ToListAsync();
        }
```

But I get the following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: m.Id, 
ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: myTable
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False

    .First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

Comment: EF Core version please.

Comment: @IvanStoev Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 5.0.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update (EF Core 6.0):**

EF Core 6.0 did add support for some additional operators to `GroupBy` result set, including the one in question, so now the original LINQ query should work intact.

**Original:**

Since currently (hopefully v6.0 would add some) EF Core does not support `GroupBy` result operators other than key/aggregates projections, it cannot be used to implement the *top N items per group* function, which is what you basically are trying to do (for `N == 1`).

So as a workaround (without 3rd party extensions), you have to do that manually by (1) using subquery for selecting the unique keys, and then (2) using it as filter for correlated limiting subquery. e.g. something like

```
var query = db.myTable.Select(x => new { x.Id }).Distinct() // (1)
    .SelectMany(key => db.myTable.Where(x => x.Id == key.Id).Take(1)) // (2)
    // The rest is the same as the original
    .Select(item => new myModel
    {
        Id = item.Id,
        Name = item.Name,
        ...
    });
```

Comment: Nice solution Ivan!

Comment: Thanks @Svyatoslav, poor man tricks you know :-) The sad thing is that the final SQL query joins 2 subqueries with the second being exactly what is needed (`ROW_NUMBER() OVER...`)

Comment: thank you, your codes work fine, Just a question, is your method better or the answer that Mahdi gave? Better means faster loading and working with a lot of data (5000 until 20000)

Comment: @gittest See my comment under other answer. The difference is that this is executed server side and returns only the data needed, while the other retrieves all the data and then performs the grouping/filtering in memory. Thus I'm considering this to be generally better. In reality, it depends on how many duplicates are in the database table, and how many properties (columns) it has.

Answer (score 1):

First, change your `var` to `IEnumerable<HWGPackageModel>`

Second, add `AsEnumerable()` before GroupBy

```
public static IEnumerable<myModel> GetAllItems()
        {
            
            var db = new dbContext();
            IEnumerable<myModel> query =
            from item in db.myTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
            select new myModel
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    ...
                };

            return query;
        }
```

Comment: This would perform the operation in memory (after retrieving all the items from the database), which in general is not good and is the main reason client evaluation was removed in EFC 3.0